# Why are some of my Bitbucket's PHP composer's libs uploaded as links?

Tags: php, git, composer-php, bitbucket

My composer.json is :

```
{
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir" : "php/lib"
    },
    "require": {
        "h0gar/xpath" : "*",
        "hellogerard/jobby": "dev-master",
        ...
    },
}
```

.igitignore is

```
php/config.php
```

I have sync my local project to a private bitbucket repository. When deploying code from this repository I get some error because of missing libraries. While Investigating, I figured out, some of the libs (for example : hellogerard/jobby) I installed through composer where "uploaded" to my bitbucket repo as "links", here is what I see :

[image: jobby missing dir]

others are send to remote repo correctly (I mean full dirs and files).

I know it is best practice to add my composer's vendor directoy to .gitignore and install libs on each machine but this should still work and for some little projects speed and easy are better than good practice ? Anyway my curiosity wants to know what this bitbucket link means !

Thanks for your thoughts ...

Comment: You should not be committing the dependencies to your repository. You should ignore the vendor folder, and then install your dependencies are part of deployment. If you're concerned about your deployment depending on external resources that could go down, use a Satis mirror.

Comment: Yes I ended doing it and removing my vendor-dir part because jobby NEEDS to be in vendor directory otherwise its fails loading. I also was doing so because of private package I didn't want to add ssh key each time I was using it ... Thanks for the Satis tip !

Answer (score 0):

The "link" you talk about looks like "git submodule". It's a link to another git repository. This was used before composer times as technique to reference git repository at particular commit.

Now I would recommend you to add `composer.json` to the `jobby` repository and use it as standard package.

Comment: There is already a composer.json file in jobby package, souldntt I delete it instead ?

Comment: No, use it instead. What's the "name" in it? Is it private package?

Comment: No private :  "name": "hellogerard/jobby"

Comment: Great, you can install it in your own package just by calling `composer require hellogerard/jobby`, see: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#the-require-key